# jQuery find element outside typeahead "block"

Tags: jquery, typeahead

I'm trying to code a dynamic form where you can add multiple engines to a vehicle. Here is a get method that retreive form html, add it to the DOM, then apply typeahead behavior:

```
$.get("/editor/engineForm", function(formHtml) {
    $("#engineZone").append(formHtml);

    form = $("form.engine:last");

    $(form).find("#sBrand").typeahead({
        remote: "/editor/engineModelBrand"
    });

    $(form).find("#sModel").typeahead({
        remote: {
            replace : function() {
                sBrand = $(form).find("#sBrand").val();
                console.log("Brand :" + sBrand);
                return "/editor/engineModelModel?sBrand=" + sBrand
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Notice the cascading typeahead completion: sModel.typeahead.remote uses the value of sBrand for its request.

The problem is when I have multiple forms:

```
$(form).find("#sBrand").val();
```

Returns the value for the input#sBrand in last form created, not in the one corresponding to the current input#sModel.

Here is the Html code to illustrate :

```
<div class="engine">

    <form action="/editor/engineSave" method="GET" class="engine">  

        <div class="clearfix  " id="sBrand_field">
            <label for="sBrand">sBrand</label>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="sBrand" name="sBrand" value="" class="sBrand">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix  " id="sModel_field">
            <label for="sModel">sModel</label>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="sModel" name="sModel" value="" class="sModel">
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>

<div class="engine">

    <form action="/editor/engineSave" method="GET" class="engine">

        <div class="clearfix  " id="sBrand_field">
            <label for="sBrand">sBrand</label>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="sBrand" name="sBrand" value="" class="sBrand">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix  " id="sModel_field">
            <label for="sModel">sModel</label>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="sModel" name="sModel" value="" class="sModel">
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

How can I get jquery to find the right input ?

I tried :

```
$(this).closest("div").find("#sBrand").val();

$(this).find("#sBrand").val();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(form).find("#sModel").each(function (index, elem) {
    $(elem).typeahead({
        remote: {
            replace: function () {
                sBrand = $(elem).closest(".engine").find("#sBrand").val();
                console.log("Brand :" + sBrand);
                return "/editor/engineModelModel?sBrand=" + sBrand
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Great! It works.

Actually, sBrand = $(elem).val(); gets the current input value.

But sBrand = $(elem).closest(".engine").find("#sBrand").val(); works just fine!